# How to reset the $ModuleNumber?

Tags: evaluation, scoping, symbols

According to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/%24ModuleNumber.html), we *can reset $ModuleNumber to a positive machine integer*. There is even an example in the doc:

```
$ModuleNumber = 17; {Module[{x}, x], $ModuleNumber}
```

> ```
> {x$17, 18}
> ```

However, when I try evaluating it again and again, instead of keeping `17`, the "serial number" after `$` increases *every* time.

I double checked that the `$ModuleNumber` does get reset at the beginning:

```
$ModuleNumber = 17; {$ModuleNumber, Module[{x}, x], $ModuleNumber}
```

> ```
> (* first time evaluation: *){17, x$17, 18}
> (*secend time evaluation: *){17, x$18, 19}
> (* third time evaluation: *){17, x$19, 20}
> ```
>
> ......
>
> ...

I did the test in *9.0.1 home edition* on Windows 8, and also in *10.0* on Raspberry Pi with the same result:

[image: $ModuleNumber reseting failed]

It's interesting to notice that using loop to automize the evaluation will NOT increase the number *during* the loop:

```
Do[
   Print[
         $ModuleNumber = 17;
     {$ModuleNumber, Module[{x}, x], $ModuleNumber}
        ],
   {5}]
```

> ```
> {17,x$19,20}
> {17,x$19,20}
> {17,x$19,20}
> {17,x$19,20}
> {17,x$19,20}
> ```

But

```
$ModuleNumber = 17;
Do[
   Print[
     {$ModuleNumber, Module[{x}, x], $ModuleNumber}
        ],
   {5}]
```

> ```
> {17,x$17,18}
> {18,x$18,19}
> {19,x$19,20}
> {20,x$20,21}
> {21,x$21,22}
> ```
>
> **So question:**

Do I misunderstand the documentation? What do I miss? And most importantly, how can I reset the `$ModuleNumber` so the subsequent `Module`/`Unique` will use the "serial number" I specified?

Comment: When I try it in a loop, the first time I get `{x$17, 18}`, the second `{x$18, 19}`, and then back to `{x$17, 18}` in a loop between the two

Comment: If I put them in separate lines in the same cell, I get always `{x$17, 18}`

Comment: @Rojo hmm... what's your OS? I tested on win8, win8.1 and RPi, all get the same result...

Comment: Don't forget that `$ModuleNumber` is incremented by anything that uses `Unique` or `Module`, including code used by _Mathematica_ itself. It is possible that the predictive interface stuff and other hidden things might be incrementing the counter.

Comment: From the front end, 9.0.1, W8.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a simple matter. When the code

```
$ModuleNumber = 17; 
{$ModuleNumber, Module[{x}, x], $ModuleNumber}
```

is evaluated the second time, `x$17` already exists, but `Module` must generate a new unique symbol, so it generates the next one in the sequence, `x$18`. This conclusion is supported by the fact that evaluating the following three lines of code over and over again

```
Remove[x, "x$*"];
$ModuleNumber = 17; 
{$ModuleNumber, Module[{x}, x], $ModuleNumber}
```

will give

> ```
> {17, x$17, 18}
> ```

indefinitely.

Because the output of `Module[{x}, x]` is the local variable, that variable gets associated with `Out`'s downvalues when `$HistoryLength` is not zero. So, regardless of the `$ModuleNumber`, *Mathematica* must skip forward in the local variable naming sequence until an entirely new (not already existing) symbol can be created.

Comment: @Silvia he's right

Comment: @Silvia When the output of your module is the variable, the variable get's associated with `Out`'s downvalues if `$HistoryLength` is not zero. So, regardless of the `$ModuleNumber`, it gets skipped until a free symbol is found.

Comment: @Silvia my weird behaviour was due to the fact that I had `$HistoryLength` set to 1

Comment: @Rojo Ding ding ding! `$HistoryLength` is what gave me a different behaviour as well. All's good when you set it to 0. This answer appears to be exactly the reason for the behaviour seen in the OP. One can also demonstrate that Module/Unique will skip a symbol if it already exists in the symbol table (as expected) with `x5 = 1;Table[Unique["x"], {10}]` (in a new session)

Comment: @Rojo rm-rf I see! Indeed it's the reason. The documentation warns *naming conflicts*, and I carelessly misread (well didn't read the whole sentence...) it as I can do intentional naming conflicts by reseting the `$ModuleNumber`, didn't realize the mechanism for avoiding conflicts is still valid.. Many thanks m_goldberg! I feel so silly...

Comment: I added Rojo's explanation for completeness, hope you don't mind :)